# Trying to implement an 8 point 1D DCT-II in labview; can only put one value in my output array

Tags: signal-processing, labview

I am trying to implement a 1D DCT type II filter in Labview. The formula for this can be seen [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/0/1/e0186125d4115a3883a6a20871bd8eda.png)

As you can see xk = the sum of a sum function involving an iteration of n.

[image: This is a block diagram of my attempt]

As far as I know the nested for loop should handle the function with the shift registers keeping a running total of the output. My problem lies with the output the the matrix xk. There is either only one output to the matrix or each output over-writes the last output due to no indexig. trying to put the matrix inside the for loop results in an error between the shift register and the matrix:

```
You have connected two terminals of different types. 
The source is a double and the sink is a 1D array of double
```

Anyone know how I can index the output to the array?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work. Please check the math.

[image]

Comment: Sorry - but I'm completely new to labview and I am confused - how do I "link" my array to the Xn input and Xk output? Also - is k "linked" to something else. Thanks

Comment: Those are controls and indicators. You can create them on the front panel or right-click on a wire and Create -> Control/Indicator.

Also, please have a look at the following:
http://www.ni.com/gettingstarted/labviewbasics/

Comment: I had a look through everything and seem to have figured it out. What was tripping me up was the auto-indexing vs passing the array into the for-loop, now I've figured out I can just right click where the array is being passed into the loop and change these settings. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

the inner for-loop will run either 8 times, or however many elements are in the array xn. LabVIEW uses whichever number is smaller to determine the iteration count. So if xn is empty, the for loop wont run at all.  If it's 20, the for loop will run 8 times.

Regardless, the outer loop will always run 8 times, so xk will have 8 elements total.

Also, shift registers that do not initialize a value at the beginning of a for or while loop can cause problems, unless you mean to do that.  The value stored in the shift register after running the first time could be a problem the second time you go to run it.

Comment: wrt the shift register thing, I had noticed that but didn't know why it was happening. Now I know.